# Problems with understanding the proof of noetherian ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

If $M$ is an $R$-module, the the following are equivalent:
1. M is finitely generated
2. M satisfies the ascending chain condition
3. Every non-empty set of submodules of M contains at least one maximal element

The proof: 3-> 1 Suppose 1 is false, so there is a submodule M' of M that is not finitely generated. We will show that the set of $S$ of all finitely generated submodules of $M'$ does not have a maximal element, which will be a contradiction. Suppose $S$ does not have a maximal element L. Since L is finely generated and $L \subsetneq M'$ and M' is not finitely generated, there is an $a\in M'$ such that $a \neq L$. The $L' = L + Ra$ is an element of S that strictly contains the presumed maximal element L, a contradiction.

My problem with understanding this proof is that why we can assume that submodules of M' also contain a maximal element when the statement is M contains a least element. I don't think submodules of M' is necessarily a submodule of M.

Comment: You should add that $R$ is a noetherian ring. Furthermore one should point out that the equivalence of $2$ and $3$ is formal, while the fact that $1$ suffices to imply $2$ and $3$ really needs that $R$ is noetherian.

Comment: @MooS isn't a noetherian ring a ring that satisfies any of the statement above?

Comment: @user136266 Certainly not. I think I may see the source of your confusion, and I expanded my answer a bit to explain. Let me know if it's helpful or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Suppose 1 is false, so there is a submodule M' of M that is not finitely generated."

That is not the negation of "$M$ is finitely generated" unless you are talking about $M=M'$. Using the notation $M'$ basically serves no purpose.

So, you are not really having any problems in your proof of 3 implying 1.

---

> @MooS isn't a noetherian ring a ring that satisfies any of the statement above?

No, definitely not. It occurs to me you might be muddling a few problems together.

For any right $R$ module $M$, consider the following statements:

1. The poset of submodules of $M$ satisfies the ascending chain condition.
2. The poset of submodules of $M$ satisfies the maximal condition
3. All submodules of $M$ are finitely generated
4. $M$ is finitely generated.

The first three are always equivalent, and the first three always imply the fourth, but #4 is *not* equivalent to the others.

If, in addition, $R$ is right Noetherian, *then* the fourth condition becomes equivalent to the first three.

Now in your original post, you have been talking about conditions 1, 2, and 4 (on my list), but when you went to do your proof, you immediately started by negating 3 (on my list.)  So this may be the source of your confusion.

If you stop using $M'$ and replace it with $M$, you will have given a correct proof that a Noetherian module is finitely generated. On the other hand, if you want to prove 1$\implies$3 (on my list) then you can use exactly the same argument for an arbitrary submodule $M'$ of $M$, as long as you realize that conditions $1$ and $2$ pass to submodules.

> I don't think submodules of M' is necessarily a submodule of M.

A submodule of a submodule of $M$ is a submodule of $M$: being a submodule is a transitive relation. It's straightforward to check. Maybe you are thinking of ideals in ring theory, because being an ideal is not normally a transitive relation.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. What I meant is the in the end of the proofWe found that S cannot contain a maximal element. and the proof claims that this is a contradiction. However, I do not think so, because S is a set of submodules of M' but not a set of submodules of M. Statement 3 says "submodule of M"

Comment: @user136266 If $M$ is an $R$-module, and $M'$ is a submodule of $M$, and $M''$ is a submodule of $M'$, then $M''$ is a submodule of $M$.

Comment: @user73985 i don't think this is true. It is definitely not true for ideals so i think it is not true for module. I am thinking of a counterexample now. Or is it really true?

Comment: @user136266 Incidentally, what user73985 says is just fine. Submodules of submodules are submodules.